# Database Tuning for 3rd Party Software Database

Tags: sql-server, index-tuning, performance-tuning

I'm starting out as a SQL Server consultant trying to focus on maintenance and performance improvements.  I'm using Brent Ozar's first responder's kit and tools.  I've had good success with one client with an in-house developed application.

I have a new client that is asking for maintenance performance tuning on a database that is solely for a 3rd party application.  I don't think the changes I would make (e.g. moving the tempdb from c drive to another drive) would break anything. I'm just concerned about doing this without consulting with the 3rd party.  Then again they would probably just say no.

The question is, is it a good practice to performance tune a database created and used by 3rd party software?

More specifically, are there some things I should avoid?  (like index changes)

Comment: "is it a good practice to performance tune a database created and used by 3rd party" -- do you have a choice?

Comment: My general recommendation when dealing with 3rd party software databases is to materialize the data elsewhere so that you maximize your flexibility with tuning the database and minimize breaking the licensing agreement / warranty that customer has with their 3rd party software. This can be achieved a multitude of ways such as with Replication, Availability Groups, or Log Shipping, etc. I'm not a fan of modifying the source database of a 3rd party vendor application, but have no qualms with modifying a copy of it.

Comment: You also have to consider liability. If your changes break something the vendor may not be sympathetic. That leaves the client seeking recompense from yourself.

Comment: I don't understand why this is marked off-topic.  It deals with DBA work, SQL Server specifically, and how to deal with 3rd party databases.  If this is not the correct stack exchange forum for this question then which forum is the correct one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a (presumably) paying client that asks you to improve their database performance. You realise that the database is part of/set up by a 3d party software package. I'm going to assume that there is indeed a tangible performance issue and you have some ideas how to address it.

You have alternatives.

1. Your client is also that 3d party vendor's client and has a support contract with them. With the help of your client you contact the vendor, explain in [great detail](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions) what the performance problem is, and request their advice. After few<sup>1</sup> iterations you together arrive at a state that is acceptable to your client. You collect your payment and go celebrate Christmas/New Year/Nawruz/Масленица/Purim/Independence Day as the case may be.
2. The above doesn't work because the client's support contract has expired/the vendor is not responsive/you're feeling adventurous. You then try your ideas, one at a time, to see if any combination of them resolves the problem. You get lucky and the problem is solved (temporarily). You then collect your payment, prepare yourself to repeat all the work after the next 3d party software upgrade (automation and [IaC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrastructure_as_code) are your friends), and go celebrate as appropriate.
3. Neither of the above works. You come back here, explain your problem in [great detail](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions), and hope that the hive mind finds a solution. If it works, you collect your payment etc.
4. Neither of the above works. You hang up your hat and go flip burgers/deliver fast food/clean gutters/enjoy your hobby.

Addressing the comment that states:

> the client doesn't have specific performance issues, but just generally thinks things can be faster

This is a Bad Thing™. One should never try to make "things" "generally faster": the client and you will certainly have different understanding of what "things", "generally", and "faster" mean, so you will never be able to come to an agreement whether the job has been accomplished.

You need to grill your client until they tell you their worst pain point or the exact thing they want to be faster and by how much. If you are unable to make them confess, *you* will need to find one thing that you believe can be *meaningfully* improved and have the client agree that this is what they want you to do.

If you don't do that, your job will never be complete and the client will never be happy. Neither of you want that.

---

1 -- Many.

Comment: So the client doesn't have specific performance issues, but just generally thinks things can be faster.  With the help of Brent Ozar's tools I can find out what issues there are.  I guess I'm trying to figure out if it's worth my time doing that or should I just point them to the vendor, and move on to other work.  I don't know if that changes your answer, but I do appreciate the options you give.

Comment: Different applications have different support policies, i.e. for Sharepoint adding an index will invalidate your support agreement - other applications have different agreements. Some optimisations like separating the disks for tempdb are generally safe, note that SQL Server now allows things like plan guides which are specifically aimed at helping in the situations where you don't have access to the source code.
The quickest improvement will come from upgrading SQL to the latest version that the application supports.

Comment: No one but you can tell whether something is worth your time. I personally try not to engage, if I can help it, in projects where someone thinks "things" "can" "generally" be made "faster".